# Dynamic programming ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I'm getting this weird exception, I don't really understand why.. I tried debugging and found out that it goes wrong when running:

```
opt[i][j] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

and when i == 0 and j == 1, but this shouldn't happen since in this case opt is a 9x6 matrix.

This is my code:

```
public class Versie3 {

    private int desCap;
    private int currentCap;
    private int maxCap;
    private int timeSlot;
    private static ArrayList<Double> prices;
    private double[][] opt = new double[timeSlot + 1][maxCap + 1];

    public Versie3() throws FileNotFoundException {

    }

    public void readInput(String s) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(s);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

        timeSlot = sc.nextInt();
        maxCap = sc.nextInt();
        currentCap = sc.nextInt();
        desCap = sc.nextInt();
        prices = new ArrayList<Double>(timeSlot);

        while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            prices.add(sc.nextDouble());

        }
    }

    public double calculateOptimal() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= timeSlot; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= maxCap; j++) 
            {
                if (i == 0) 
                {
                    if (j != desCap) 
                    {

                        opt[i][j] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; // <--here it goes Wrong!
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        opt[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                } 
                else if (j == 0) 
                {
                    opt[i][j] = Math.min(opt[i - 1][j],
                            opt[i - 1][j + 1]
                                    - prices.get(i-1));
                } 
                else if (j == maxCap) 
                {
                    opt[i][j] = Math.min(opt[i - 1][j],
                            opt[i - 1][j - 1]
                                    + prices.get(i-1));
                } 
                else 
                {
                    opt[i][j] = Math.min(Math.min(opt[i - 1][j],
                    opt[i - 1][j - 1]
                    + prices.get(i - 1)),opt[i - 1][j + 1]- prices.get(i-1));
                }
            }
        }
        return opt[timeSlot][currentCap];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Versie3 v3 = new Versie3();
        v3.readInput("input.txt");
        System.out.println("prices: " + prices.toString());
        System.out.println("timeSlot: " + v3.timeSlot);
        System.out.println("maxCap: " + v3.maxCap);
        System.out.println("currentCap: " + v3.currentCap);
        System.out.println("desCap: " + v3.desCap);
        //System.out.println("minimum cost: "+v3.calculateOptimal());
        System.out.println(v3.prices.size());

    }

}
```

And this is the input file I'm reading:

```
8 5 2 5
2.2 3 5 6.5 5 5 3 1.8
```

In this case:

```
timeSlot = 8
maxCap = 5
currentCap = 2 
desCap = 5
```

the second row shows the prices per time slot. so 8 in total.

I appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: +1 well-structured question with all necessary info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your array with `maxCap` and `timeSlot` while they still have the default value of `0`.  `readInput()` has not been called yet so how could you know what size to make the array?

Create the array after you read in `maxCap` and `timeSlot`.

Answer (score 3):

`opt` is getting intialized at construction time *before* `timeSlot` and `maxcap` are set.

So you create an array

```
private double[][] opt = new double[0 + 1][0 + 1];
```

You have to create the array in the `readInput` method after the user has entered the values.

Answer (score 1):

You init your opt array before you determine what maxCap equals.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object of the class `Versie3`, `maxCap` and  `timeSlot` take their default value of `0` and the array `opt` is created with the size of `1 x 1`.

After this you go and read the file which rewrites the values of `maxCap` and  `timeSlot` but the array size remains **unchanged**.

To fix this, allocate memory for the array in function `readFile` after you've read the dimensions.